# extjs firsttimer having problems loading library

Tags: extjs

I understand this being a java based framework but I wanted to try and implement a widget within an asp.net application since it is mainly javascript stuff involved. I added the libraries to my project folder directory and it seems like the jar files are not loading as expected.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 
      (Not Found) http://localhost:52856/extjs/ext-debug.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 
      (Not Found) http://localhost:52856/extjs/examples/app/simple/app.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 
     (Not Found) http://localhost:52856/extjs/examples/shared/include-ext.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 
     (Not Found) http://localhost:52856/extjs/examples/shared/options-toolbar.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 
     (Not Found) http://localhost:52856/portal.js
```

Does Extjs have a CDM where we can load the libraries from like google.apis.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/examples/app/simple/app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/examples/shared/include-ext.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/examples/shared/options-toolbar.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/examples/portal/portal.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
     Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.app', 'classes');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="portal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.require([
        'Ext.layout.container.*',
        'Ext.resizer.Splitter',
        'Ext.fx.target.Element',
        'Ext.fx.target.Component',
        'Ext.window.Window',
        'Ext.app.Portlet',
        'Ext.app.PortalColumn',
        'Ext.app.PortalPanel',
        'Ext.app.Portlet',
        'Ext.app.PortalDropZone',
        'Ext.app.GridPortlet',
        'Ext.app.ChartPortlet'
    ]);

    Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.app.Portal');
    });
</script>

</head>


<body>

<span id="app-msg" style="display:none;"></span>
```

EDIT

I accepted the answer below but find myself with endless errors now when trying to load other files. I thought the ext-all.js basically loaded all the references and you had to just define these in your functions but I guess I am lost again

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404  
   (Not Found)  http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-base.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null 
    ext-all-debug.js:19552
Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined exporting.js:9
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addCls' ext-all.js:21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extjs has a CDN.  You can access it at: http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all.js

EDIT:
From your post, it looks like you're trying to import the whole example into your project.  I'd start smaller.  Here's an example of how to load a window into your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all.js">    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    Ext.require([
        'Ext.window.Window'
    ]);

     Ext.onReady(function () {
         var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
             title: "my first ext window",
             width: 250,
             height: 150             
         });
         window.show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry could you help me with one more thing

Comment: added an example of loading a window.  Adding the whole content of the example is possible, of course, but it's better to start from the basics.